# Special characters must be escaped: [>]

Tags: html

Ok, I'm lost.  I created this unordered list with 6 items (no bullets intentional).  the problem is the last two items of the list are coming up with "Special characters must be escaped: [>]" in Dreamweaver CC 2017. Call me blind, but I am just not seeing any special characters in those lines.  Am I missing something obvious?

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li>The Oscar is only worth $1</li>
    <li>It takes 10 days to make one Oscar</li>
    <li>The statuettes are 24K gold plated, bronze underneath</li>
    <li>For 3 years during WWII, the statues were made of plaster</li>
    <li>>Over 3000 Oscars have been awarded</li>
    <li>>The statues are 8.5 pounds and 13.5 inches tall</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have extra greater than in those as you can see and as the message says those should be escaped or rather encoded

Comment: you should either replace the two extra greater than signs at the start of the last two list items. or replaces them with `&gt;` html entities

Comment: You probably would have spotted them right away by temporarily removing the inline style to preview the content.

Comment: OMFG!  I looked at that for 20+ minutes and totally missed that.  I feel like such a fool!  Thanks all!

Comment: @Zach Saucier et all --My apologies for the question being off topic.  I honestly thought I had a coding error that I was just not seeing.  The fact it was something so simple makes me feel an inch and a half tall!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're in your last two items:

```
    <li>>Over 3000 Oscars have been awarded</li>
    <li>>The statues are 8.5 pounds and 13.5 inches tall</li>
```

Strictly speaking though, you don't *need* to encode them in this context; doing so is always good advice, but what you have here isn't invalid.

But in any case, judging by the content they probably weren't supposed to be there in the first place and so your first instinct is probably to remove them; go ahead and do so.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that!  I guess the simplest things are the hardest to see.  I think it is bedtime now!